# How to navigate vscode save changes before closing dialog without using mouse?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In macOS vscode, when I close a file that has some changes made to it, I get a dialog on top. How do i navigate the buttons here with just my keyboard?

The screenshot doesn't show it but it defaults to the Save button.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know if VS Code follows normal Mac conventions but, if it does, Return should select the default button (Save, presumably); Escape should cancel; and Command-D or possibly Command-Delete should select Don't Save.

Also, if you have System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access set to "All controls", the Tab key should move focus among the buttons and Space will press the one with focus. If you don't normally have that set that way, Control-F7 will toggle it on.

Comment: It is helpful to note, `Don't Save` and `Cancel` have a border indicating they are selected. When the `Save` button is selected there is NO indication it is selected.

Comment: Thank you for this info. In Mac OS 10.15 it looks like it's System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, and then at the bottom of the dialog "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls".